# My node.js json parse function throws error

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

***[ JAVASCRIPT NEWBIE ]***

Hi,

I am trying to parse json data to extract different values but I am getting errors. Could you please help?

**JSON Data**

[image: JSON DATA]

**Raw JSON data sample:**

```
{"records":{"expiryDates":["03-Jun-2021","10-Jun-2021","17-Jun-2021","24-Jun-2021","01-Jul-2021","08-Jul-2021","15-Jul-2021","22-Jul-2021","29-Jul-2021","26-Aug-2021","30-Sep-2021","30-Dec-2021"],"data":[{"strikePrice":18000,"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021","PE":{"strikePrice":18000,"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021","underlying":"BANKNIFTY","identifier":"OPTIDXBANKNIFTY30-09-2021PE18000.00","openInterest":1,"changeinOpenInterest":0,"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,"totalTradedVolume":0,"impliedVolatility":0,"lastPrice":0.25,"change":0,"pChange":0,"totalBuyQuantity":23100,"totalSellQuantity":0,"bidQty":10000,"bidprice":5,"askQty":0,"askPrice":0,"underlyingValue":35141.45}},{"strikePrice":23000,"expiryDate":"24-Jun-2021","PE":{"strikePrice":23000,"expiryDate":"24-Jun-2021","underlying":"BANKNIFTY","identifier":"OPTIDXBANKNIFTY24-06-2021PE23000.00","openInterest":534,"changeinOpenInterest":-6,"pchangeinOpenInterest":-1.1111111111111112,"totalTradedVolume":82,"impliedVolatility":63.23,"lastPrice":9.5,"change":-2.5,"pChange":-20.833333333333336,"totalBuyQuantity":2775,"totalSellQuantity":875,"bidQty":50,"bidprice":9.5,"askQty":50,"askPrice":9.95,"underlyingValue":35141.45}},{"strikePrice":24000,"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021","PE":{"strikePrice":24000,"expiryDate":"30-Sep-2021","underlying":"BANKNIFTY","identifier":"OPTIDXBANKNIFTY30-09-2021PE24000.00","openInterest":0,"changeinOpenInterest":0,"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,"totalTradedVolume":0,"impliedVolatility":0,"lastPrice":0,"change":0,"pChange":0,"totalBuyQuantity":20575,"totalSellQuantity":0,"bidQty":5000,"bidprice":5,"askQty":0,"askPrice":0,"underlyingValue":35141.45}},{"strikePrice":24000,"expiryDate":"30-Dec-2021","PE":{"strikePrice":24000,"expiryDate":"30-Dec-2021","underlying":"BANKNIFTY","identifier":"OPTIDXBANKNIFTY30-12-2021PE24000.00","openInterest":11,"changeinOpenInterest":0,"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,"totalTradedVolume":0,"impliedVolatility":0,"lastPrice":180,"change":0,"pChange":0,"totalBuyQuantity":100,"totalSellQuantity":0,"bidQty":50,"bidprice":151.55,"askQty":0,"askPrice":0,"underlyingValue":35141.45}},{"strikePrice":24000,"expiryDate":"24-Jun-2021","CE":{"strikePrice":24000,"expiryDate":"24-Jun-2021","underlying":"BANKNIFTY","identifier":"OPTIDXBANKNIFTY24-06-2021CE24000.00","openInterest":1,"changeinOpenInterest":0,"pchangeinOpenInterest":0,"totalTradedVolume":0,"impliedVolatility":0,"lastPrice":9223.8,"change":0,"pChange":0,"totalBuyQuantity":3650,"totalSellQuantity":2900,"bidQty":750,"bidprice":11073.95,"askQty":500,"askPrice":11544.4,"underlyingValue":35141.45},"PE":
```

**My node.js code:**

```
async function formatDataAndStore(resp){
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{
    //let myDate = new Date();
    //let currentTime = myDate.getHours()*100 + Math.floor(myDate.getMinutes()/5)*5;

    (resp.records.data).forEach(element => {
        console.log(JSON.parse(element.PE));
    });

    })
}
```

**Error that I am getting:**

```
> (node:12578) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected
> token o in JSON at position 1
>     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
>     at /Users/manjulamkumar/Desktop/myRepo/DEV/OptionChain/server.js:79:26
>     at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
>     at /Users/manjulamkumar/Desktop/myRepo/DEV/OptionChain/server.js:78:25
>     at new Promise (<anonymous>)
>     at formatDataAndStore (/Users/manjulamkumar/Desktop/myRepo/DEV/OptionChain/server.js:74:12)
>     at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/manjulamkumar/Desktop/myRepo/DEV/OptionChain/server.js:55:15)
>     at Query.<anonymous> (/Users/manjulamkumar/Desktop/myRepo/DEV/OptionChain/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:526:10)
>     at Query._callback (/Users/manjulamkumar/Desktop/myRepo/DEV/OptionChain/node_modules/mysql/lib/Connection.js:488:16)
>     at Query.Sequence.end (/Users/manjulamkumar/Desktop/myRepo/DEV/OptionChain/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/sequences/Sequence.js:83:24)
> (Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was
> created) (node:12578) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of
> an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise
> which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on
> unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag
> `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see
> https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode).
> (rejection id: 2) (node:12578) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled
> promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections
> that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a
> non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: What is logged if you remove the `JSON.parse` from your log line? Is it already json?

Comment: still get the same error however when I log element.strikePrice it works but it is unable to read inside PE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its already parsed, if not how could you do resp.records.data? Hence I would suggest you to do something like

```
resp.records.data.map(e => console.log(JSON.stringify(e.PE)))
```

or

```
resp.records.data.map(e => console.log(e.PE))
```